# alert showing once instead of several times ScriptManager asp.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager, registerstartupscript

I experience an issue using `alert('mytext');` through `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()`.

The problem is, when I use it in a loop, for example, by writting :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Hello World');", true);
}
```

the alert is displayed once, instead of three times.

To be precise, the function takes 5 parameters, which are :

- `Control control` : control of the page
- `Type typeOfControl` : type of the `Control`
- `string key` : key used to identify the JS script
- `string script` : the JS script itself
- `boolean addScriptTags` : put script into `<script></script>` or not

The essence of the problem is I can't specify another `key`. I tryied to use milliseconds to identify each Script but it seems the Script is faster and so have the same amount of millisecond (and I cannot be more precised with time...).

**QUESTION :** How could I use a possible unique idenifier to the `key` parameters ? Or is there an alternative ?

Comment: Just Append i with Key.
like : alert1, alert2, alert3

Comment: I would do this, but the reality is I used this alert in a more complex case so I cannot always rely in a counter.